# How to copy the array to UIImages into another array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiimage

I am trying to change the tableView content on for every collectionview cell, for that i am making an empty array and i'll change the array data for every cell clicked. i am unable to copy data from an array to another.

This is swift 4.2, and i am just trying to learn the stuff, so no backend is involved.

```
var PictureArray = [UIImage(named: "s1") , UIImage(named: "s2"), UIImage(named: "s3"), UIImage(named: "s4"), UIImage(named: "s5") ]

copyArray.append(PictureArray)
```

and error is

> Value of optional type 'UIImage?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'UIImage'

Comment: share copyArray declaration code, what datatype does it have?

Comment: If you want all item in your copy array then simply why don't you use copyArray = PictureArray.

Comment: @MumtazHussain mumtaz bhai, chakkar aesy tha k mujhy aik he screen p table view aur collection view change karna tha, to main chah raha tha k har collection view p click honay p array change karun, uskay liye mene array copy karna the, lekin ab mene isko logically easier way main kar lia hai, btw copyarray was of UIImage type. and was giving the error  "'UIImage?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'UIImage'"

Comment: @Abhishek i tried this way too, error was same, and now i solved this problem by using some other logic other than copying array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code:

```
var PictureArray = [UIImage(named: "s1") , UIImage(named: "s2"), UIImage(named: "s3"), UIImage(named: "s4"), UIImage(named: "s5") ]
var cpArray:[[UIImage]] = []
cpArray.append(PictureArray as! [UIImage])
```

here cpArray contains PictureArray in 0th index.

```
You can access 1st image of pictureArray using cpArray[0][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
var PictureArray = [UIImage(named: "s1") , UIImage(named: "s2"), UIImage(named: "s3"), UIImage(named: "s4"), UIImage(named: "s5") ]
let arrCopy = pictures.map{$0}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UIImage(named : "Image Name")` always return an `optional UIImage`.

```
var PictureArray = [UIImage(named: "s1") , UIImage(named: "s2"), UIImage(named: "s3"), UIImage(named: "s4"), UIImage(named: "s5") ]
```

clearly `PictureArray` array is of this type `[UIImage?]` or `Array<UIImage?>`

you are trying to insert the array to copy array , from the error message it is clearly assumed that this is `[UIImage]`

clearly `[UIImage] != [UIImage?]`

that is why you are getting error.

You may do by using higher order method

```
PictureArray = PictureArray.map{$0 as? UIImage}

copyArray.append(PictureArray)
```

or if you want to use a childish type coding , play a loop inside the `PictureArray`

```
for case let image in PictureArray {
    if image != nil {
        copyArray.append(image)
    }
}
```